# Wp Rest APi - check domain in permission_callback

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I'm developing a plugin based on WP Rest API and i need to make sure only authorized users access it. I will be providing an API key to authenticate. However, I also want to associate the API key to a certain domain (meaning, it should only work if it's being used from the authorized domain(s)).

How do I check on the API side if it is being accessed from an authorized domain?

I know that when i do a "register_rest_route" i can set a function that check user permission via "permission_callback" argument. However i don't know how i can check from what domain makes the API Request.

Thanks

Comment: I am also curious about the answer to this. Any luck figuring this out yet?

Comment: no , not yet- please let me know if you figure it out